# How do I create a byte array from a mix of hex and strings in Go?

Tags: arrays, go

I'm trying to implement the data specified here:

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries#Request_Format

I'm creating a byte array that needs to end up looking like this:

```
0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x54 0x53 0x6F 0x75 0x72 0x63 0x65 0x20 0x45 0x6E 0x67 0x69 0x6E 0x65 0x20 0x51 0x75 0x65 0x72 0x79 0x00
```

Broken down, it is just some bytes in a header:

```
0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x54
```

Then after that, the zero terminated string "Source Engine Query".

I was able to get this to work in a very ugly fashion, but I know there has to be a cleaner path:

```
message := []byte("xxxxxSource Engine Queryx")
message[0] = 0xFF
message[1] = 0xFF
message[2] = 0xFF
message[3] = 0xFF
message[4] = 0x54
message[24] = 0x00
```

I've tried using slices like this, but I can't figure out how to use it with non string values:

```
message := make([]byte, 25)
copy(message[5:], "Source Engine Query")
```

That works, but then I can't figure out how to add the "0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x54" to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

It's also bytes.Buffer https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer among other approaches, quite fast and has couple of handy methods

```
message := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x54})
message.WriteString("Source Engine Query")
message.WriteByte(0x00)
message.WriteTo(os.Stdout) //or write to some other io.Writer you want, say net.Conn
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of working on this, I of course figure it out after I ask here...

```
message := []byte("\xff\xff\xff\xff\x54Source Engine Query\x00")
```

This works perfect. I found it here:

https://blog.golang.org/strings